# I'm having an unavoidable Quartus Syntax error

Tags: verilog

Here is the code I have written:

```
reg number;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
case(SW[3:1])
        000: number = 32h'A65D;
        001: number = 32h'BAB9;
        010: number = 32h'9430;
        011: number = 32h'8BEB;
        100: number = 32h'7CB8;
        101: number = 32h'62F1;
        110: number = 32h'6EF9;
        111: number = 32h'5D5C;
        default: number = 32h'0000;
endcase
end
```

I keep getting an error in quartus for every line saying:

> "Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at test.v(181) near text "h";
>   expecting ";""

How I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a bit width for `number`; it is currently 1-bit wide and you likely want 32 bits.  You need to add a size and a base radix (`3'b`) to each of the case items:

```
reg [31:0] number;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
case(SW[3:1])
        3'b000: number <= 32'hA65D;
        3'b001: number <= 32'hBAB9;
        3'b010: number <= 32'h9430;
        3'b011: number <= 32'h8BEB;
        3'b100: number <= 32'h7CB8;
        3'b101: number <= 32'h62F1;
        3'b110: number <= 32'h6EF9;
        3'b111: number <= 32'h5D5C;
        default: number <= 32'h0000;
endcase
end
```

You should use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for sequential logic.

UPDATE: ...and of course after seeing Eugenio Lyatte's answer, fix the `'h` syntax error, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need change `32h'A65D` for `32'hA65D`. This will be resolve your error.

```
reg [31:0]number
always @(posedge clk)
begin
case(SW[3:1])
3'b000: number <= 32'hA65D;
3'b001: number <= 32'hBAB9;
    3'b010: number <= 32'h9430;
    3'b011: number <= 32'h8BEB;
    3'b100: number <= 32'h7CB8;
    3'b101: number <= 32'h62F1;
    3'b110: number <= 32'h6EF9;
    3'b111: number <= 32'h5D5C;
endcase
```